# NodeJS: Google Map image of specified location

Tags: node.js, google-maps

Here is the python code for storing google maps view of specified location in png format
Python: [Google Map Image of Specified Location](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-google-map-image-specified-location-using-google-static-maps-api/)

How can I achieve this in NodeJS

P.S. I want to write it in a file directly instead of document.write(), like using fs.writeFile() or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a package which we can use to achieve this [Google Static Map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-static-map)